# Cakephp habtm deep conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

suppose you have those model relations:

Offer HABTM Category

How would you build the find conditions to find all the categories that have at least one offer. In the same time the Offer should be Offer.enabled => 1. So find all the categories with at least one enabled offer. The conditions to check in the offer model are several, but once I can check for the enabled, I think I will be able to check for any other field.

I could bind the habtm model to Category, but in this case I can't check the Offer.enabled condition. Maybe somehow using containable?
The sql query would be :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category.nome from categories as Category
LEFT JOIN categories_offers AS CategoriesOffer
ON (CategoriesOffer.category_id = Category.id)
LEFT JOIN offers as Offer ON (CategoriesOffer.offer_id = Offer.id)
WHERE Offer.enabled = 1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `conditions` key in your relationship definition to set the relationship up only if `Offer.enabled = 1`. Taken from the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm). eg:

```
class Category extends Model {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Offer' => array(
            'conditions' => array( 'Offer.enabled' => 1 )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is ok only if I always need that condition. The fact is the conditions change always. However I was able to get the results using the linkable behavior.